# Flurry has an interface that always responds to 400

Tags: android, flurry

I mainly use the Flurry Event function, my other management is normal, but there is always an interface 400（https://data.flurry.com/v1/flr.do），which shows the information

```
HTTP ERROR 400
Problem accessing /v1/flr.do. Reason:

X-Flurry-Api-Key apikey not present in header
Powered by Jetty://
```

My initialization code is as follows

```
FlurryAgent.Builder()
            .withLogEnabled(true)
            .withCaptureUncaughtExceptions(true)
            .withContinueSessionMillis(10000)
            .withLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE)
            .build(this.context!!, this.context!!.getString(R.string.ID_Flurry))
```

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory, "apikey not present in header". You're probably not passing it correctly, or it doesnt exist on the context

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure R.string.ID_Flurry returns your correct Flurry API-KEY.

Comment: `this.context!!.getString(R.string.ID_Flurry)`.
Try to replace this with a hard code string "Your_API_KEY". And try to replace it with other working ones. In order to see whether it's the issue of API_KEY or the initializing codes.